# Parse set applicationId quitting

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have an app that opens up right away to a login/register page. Everytime I run it, I get an error. The exception breakpoint shows that the error is in the `viewDidLoad`statement. Here it is:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()


            Parse.setApplicationId("EVH469wqjtGjbWVATySdePvjaETquQDImcYaqUjc", clientKey: "4H9sMitCWq1AaaSvFSJ3EluUOwcI3OteYwMjrlxV")
            var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
            if currentUser != nil
            {
               self.performSegueWithIdentifier("homepage", sender: AnyObject?())
            }
            else
            {

            }

}
```

The breakpoint highlights the `Parse.setApplicationId` line. I cannot figure this out for the life of me. Any help is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: It only crashes on my phone, not in the simulator... which is even weirder

Comment: Only weird ones like "trap"

Comment: What is the error if you remove the exception breakpoint?

Comment: Still a trap error. The breakpoint highlights the parse line only after I've navigated gbp

Comment: sorry, meant to say "through"